# How to use pytorch's grid_sample()?

Tags: pytorch

I am having some trouble getting `torch.nn.functional` working as I would like, illustrated by the below example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

sz = 5
input_arr = torch.from_numpy(np.arange(sz*sz).reshape(1,1,sz,sz)).float()
indices = torch.from_numpy(np.array([-1,-1, -0.5,-0.5, 0,0, 0.5,0.5, 1,1]).reshape(1, 1, 5, 2)).float()

out = F.grid_sample(input_arr, indices)
print(input_arr)
print(out)
```

Since the indices are just the diagonals of the input, I'd expect to get something like `tensor([[[[0., 6., 12., 18., 24.]]]])` (since (-1,-1) should give the top left and (1,1) should give the bottom right, according to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#grid-sample)). However, I am getting this as output to the console:

```
tensor([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
          [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
          [10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
          [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.],
          [20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]]]])
tensor([[[[ 0.0000,  4.5000, 12.0000, 19.5000,  6.0000]]]])
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried passing the argument `align_corners = True`? If you read the documentation it states that :

> WARNING
>
> When `align_corners = True`, the grid positions depend on the pixel size
> relative to the input image size, and so the locations sampled by
> `grid_sample()` will differ for the same input given at different
> resolutions (that is, after being upsampled or downsampled). The
> default behavior up to version 1.2.0 was `align_corners = True`. Since
> then, the default behavior has been changed to `align_corners = False`,
> in order to bring it in line with the default for `interpolate()`.

And to double check, I ran the code with and without `align_corners = True`, to get both the correct output you required and the incorrect output you described.

```py
# align_corners = False
out = F.grid_sample(input_arr, indices, align_corners = False)
print(out) # tensor([[[[ 0.0000,  4.5000, 12.0000, 19.5000,  6.0000]]]])
```

And

```py
# align_corners = True
out = F.grid_sample(input_arr, indices, align_corners = True)
print(out) # tensor([[[[ 0.,  6., 12., 18., 24.]]]])
```